# Как рассчитать сумму модулей элементов массива, расположенных после первого отрицательного числа?

Tags: python, list, for

Имеем:

```
import random
a = float(input("Введите число, которое будет началом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
b = float(input("Введите число, которое будет концом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
rndlist = [random.randint(a, b) for i in range(8)] # Создаем и заполняем список, состоящий из случайных чисел
```

Далее, нужно найти через цикл for(я так предполагаю) первое отрицательно число в списке и убрать из списка это отрицательное число и все те числа, которые были до него и записать оставшиеся значения в новый список. В новом списке могут быть отрицательные числа, в лабораторной сделан акцент именно НА ВЫБРОСЕ ПЕРВОГО ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО И ЧИСЕЛ ДО НЕГО(<<<PLEASE HELP)

Далее, я имею новый список, и там уже понятно:

Привожу через for все числа внутри нового списка к модулю:

```
newlist = [abs(elem) for elem in newlist]
```

И нахожу сумму всех значений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from itertools import dropwhile

rndlist = [random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(8)]  # Входные данные

it = iter(rndlist)  # Создаём итератор по списку

dropwhile_it = dropwhile(lambda x: x >= 0, it)  # Создаём итератор, который будет выкидывать все элементы до тех пор, пока не встретит первый отрицательный

next(dropwhile_it)  # Выбрасыааем первый отрицательный

result = sum(map(abs, dropwhile_it))  # Суммируем модули оставшихся элементов
```

Кстати, приводить `input()` к `float`, а затем скармливать это `randint` - не самая хорошая затея.

И учтите, что рандом может сгенерировать последовательность и без отрицательных элементов (или с одним отрицательным в конце списка).

Answer (score 0):

примерно так:

```
index = rndlist.index(next(filter(lambda n:n < 0, rndlist)))
rndlist = rndlist[index + 1:]
rndlist = [abs(el) for el in rndlist]
print(sum(rndlist))
```

- `filter(lambda n:n < 0, rndlist)` находим все элементы меньше нуля
- `next(...)` берём первый элемент среди элементов меньших нуля
- `rndlist.index(...)` находим индекс элемента
- `rndlist[index + 1:]` берём все элементы после первого отрицательного
- `[abs(el) for el in rndlist]` берём модуль всех значений
- `sum(rndlist)` находим сумму всех значений